# Font family name from font file

Tags: c#, font-family

I have a .ttf file ,i want to retrieve the font family name.

Answer (score 2):

This is most easily done by importing the System.Windows.Media namespace, which gives you more to work with and a simpler API than getting the font out of a ByteArray

```
using System.Windows.Media;

String fontFilePath = "PATH TO YOUR FONT";
GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface = new GlyphTypeface(fontFileURI);
String fontFamily = glyphTypeface.Win32FamilyNames[new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us")];
String fontFace = glyphTypeface.Win32FaceNames[new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us")];

Console.WriteLine("Font: " + fontFamily + " " + fontFace);
```

Comment: You can find many examples looking to Registry to do that, but your solution is the cleaner one. Good. Many thanks, really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have used in past, this was for web application so probably not exactly what you want. Also the Font ttf file was being stored in a database. You will need to replace the [FONTASBYTEARRAY] with an actual byte[].

There is probably a much better way to get the ttf file into the font object, but this should get you started.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Utility
{
    public class Font
    {
        public string GetFont(byte[] [FONTASBYTEARRAY])
        {
            PrivateFontCollection fc = new PrivateFontCollection();
            IntPtr pointer = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement([FONTASBYTEARRAY], 0);
            fc.AddMemoryFont(pointer, Convert.ToInt32([FONTASBYTEARRAY].Length));
            System.Drawing.Font f = new System.Drawing.Font(fc.Families[0], 10);
            FontFamily ff = f.FontFamily;
            return ff.Name;
        }
    }
}
```