# How to get Font family from the font file in a web application from a URL?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-5

I have to get the font family from a file. I have looked it up, but all answers are using WPF :.
What should I do?

I have found `FontFamily(Uri, String)` in dot net documentation. But it is in  `system.windows.media` and in `PresentationCore.dll` which is For WPF and is not available in an aspnet core application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.fontfamily.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Media_FontFamily__ctor_System_Uri_System_String_

There is another thread in StackOverflow that uses glyphTypeface But it is from the same dll/namespace in WPF.

[Font family name from font file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497755/font-family-name-from-font-file)

The best answer I've found is this, but working with Pointers in C# is very scary.

```
private static string LoadFontFamilyName(byte[] buffer)
{
  var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);

  try
  {
      var ptr = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(buffer, 0);
      using var fontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
      fontCollection.AddMemoryFont(ptr, buffer.Length);
      return fontCollection.Families[0].Name;
  }
  finally
  {
      handle.Free();
  }
```

}

Any better ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the end? Do you need to get font used in some html file?

Comment: @Alexander No, I need to store the font family (and style if possible) in the DB so we could show them to the admin without accessing the blob storage. The font would not be used in the web app at all.

Comment: @IanKemp I can of course send it to an webjob kind of process, but what I understood from your text is that I can only use windows machine to process them. Am I correct?

Comment: @AshkanSirous See my answer!

Answer (score 0):

`PrivateFontCollection` supports the [`AddFontFile(string filename)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.addfontfile?view=net-5.0) method which should do what you want. [Looking at the source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Drawing.Common/src/System/Drawing/Text/PrivateFontCollection.cs#L58), it seems this should work on both Windows and Unix/Linux systems (as long as the latter have [`libgdiplus`](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/libgdiplus/) installed).